# Two Versions of Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, oracle

We have two different web apps (Oracle forms being one) that both use java. One needs 1.7, the other 1.6 (Oracle). When we upgrade to 1.7, Oracle Forms doesn't work.

1. Is there something I can do to get Oracle forms to work with 1.7?
2. If not, how can I run multiple versions of JRE on the same machine?

Comment: What are we talking about here? Unix, Win, OSX?

Comment: Of course, you can run multiple instances of Java VM on the same machine.  Just be careful with environment variables (such as JAVA_HOME).

Comment: Have you really verified that Oracle forms doesn't work with 1.7? What happens if you try to run it?

Comment: wouldn't surprise me if Oracle Forms doesn't work with Java 7, especially if it's an older version. Years ago we had similar problems with Oracle Forms when upgrading from Java 1.4 to 1.5.

Comment: 1. Windows 7 64bit
2. When I try to run the oracle forms app with 1.7 the java windows just sits there.